# How to make cell reference another cell in excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to use VBA code to set one cell equal to a different cell, not just the value itself.  I've tried using range("C4").Value = range("B5").Value but that simply makes the value in C4 the same as that in B5, i.e if B5 = 4 then when you click on C4 it just has the number "4", not "=B5".  I tried recording a macro too to see what happens but it wasn't helpful (computer did something that was more complex than anything you'd write to accomplish the same thing).

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: `Range("C4").Formula = "=B5"`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm really still getting the hang of VBA